# NullText behavior on UltraComboBox

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics

I am using a UltraComboBox from Infragistics in a forms Task Manager screen

[image: AssignTo]

The UltraComboBox has its dropdown button hidden, and AutoCompletion is active so the user can type a couple of letters to retrieve an user name to assign someone to a task.

However, the user has the possibility to let the task "Not assigned" by clicking the eraser icon, setting the internal value of the ComboBox to `null` :

```
private void SetNotAssigned_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AssignedToComboBox.Value = null;
}
```

Instead of having my ComboBox filled with its NullText property ("Not assigned"), it is blank. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found why.

I had to put AlwaysInEditMode to false.

It looks like Infragistics is using a hidden TextBox that appears during edition and disappears afterwards. I suspect this TextBox behavior is not allways the expected one. AlwaysInEditMode seems to make that hidden TextBox on all the time.